# How to generate an event log similar to the one provided

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, event-log

The following is a log event generated by ActiveDirectory. I have an application that reads such logs and processes them. I want to make a test-application that will simulate active directory events and write similar logs to Windows event log.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
    <Provider Name="SIMULATOR" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">4769</EventID> 
    <Level>0</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Keywords>0xa0000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-02-03T10:52:20.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>35215</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>dev.local</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">WIN2K8R2-PCX$</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">dev.local</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-5-21-527455857-2257904818-3601372424-1001</Data>
    <Data Name="ServiceName">Administrator</Data> 
    <Data Name="ServiceSid">S-1-5-21-527455857-2257904818-3601372424-502</Data>
    <Data Name="TicketOptions">0x40810010</Data>
    <Data Name="Status">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="TicketEncryptionType">0x12</Data>
    <Data Name="PreAuthType">2</Data>
    <Data Name="IpAddress">84.1.24.45</Data>
    <Data Name="IpPort">0</Data>
    <Data Name="CertIssuerName" />
    <Data Name="CertSerialNumber" />
    <Data Name="CertThumbprint" />
 </EventData>
```

Please note that are multiple Data elements inside EventData element!

**If I use the following, I do get multiple data elements but how do specify the Name attribute of each Data element?**

```
string [] eventLog = new string[] {"A", "S", "D"};
EventLog log = new EventLog {Source = "source"};
log.WriteEvent(eventInstance, eventLog);
```

On [this](http://blog.dlgordon.com/2012/06/writing-to-event-log-in-net-right-way.html) article I found that I can use the manifest registered by ActiveDirectory by using EventDescriptor/EventProvider. But that doesn't write anything in event log.

I found active directory guids by following the steps given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2009/09/08/exploring-and-decoding-etw-providers-using-event-log-channels.aspx) . On my system the guids are as follows

```
Active Directory Domain Services: SAM    {8E598056-8993-11D2-819E-0000F875A064}
Active Directory: Kerberos Client        {BBA3ADD2-C229-4CDB-AE2B-57EB6966B0C4}
Active Directory: NetLogon               {F33959B4-DBEC-11D2-895B-00C04F79AB69}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one way](http://blog.dlgordon.com/2012/06/writing-to-event-log-in-net-right-way.html)

From the way I read it, you need to:

1. Use ManifestGenerator (EcManGen.exe) to create a manifest skeleton for your app.
2. Use the manifest to describe the data you want to persist.
3. Use ManifestCompiler (mc.exe) to compile the manifest, resulting in (among other things) a `.cs` and `.rc` file.
4. Use ResourceCompiler (rc.exe) to compile the `.rc` into a real resource (`.res`)
5. Use the C# Compiler (csc.exe) to compile the `.cs` and `.res` files into an assembly. *(needs to use `/unsafe`)*
6. Add the assembly to your project.
7. As an admin, run `wevutil` to add the manifest to the machine on which these logs will be logged.

Once all of this is done, you can use the `EventProvider` from the assembly or the regular `EventProvider` (with a custom `EventDescriptor`).